# How to use fabric with ssh keys?

Tags: python, python-3.x, fabric

Using **fabric 2.4** and trying to set up ssh keys to remotely connect to various linux servers?

Python is new to me, I've followed example on this site and Read python doc but still unclear to me.

Currently running python on windows and my script is able to connect to remote linux servers because i have connection string defined as follows:

```
ssh_connect = Connection(host='servername', user='user1', connect_kwargs={'password': 'blahblah'})
```

I am running python script from my window server and instead of defining the connection string, I would like it to use ssh key. I have the `id_rsa.pub` file from the linux server. I would like to setup up on my windows box and have the script use that for connections?

Answer (score 0):

You can always just pass a key via Fabric through it's command line arguments. This is definitely kind of a vague question, especially since it's running fabric on Windows, which to my knowledge is not technically supported by them, though it does work.

```
fab -i /Path/to/key
```

Source: fab --help and the official documentation [here](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/2.4/getting-started.html)